# How to read in writeBin() output from R into Java?

Tags: java, r, binary-data

Consider the following R code:

```
f <- file("test.txt", "wb")
writeBin(c(1.2, 2.3, 3.4), f)
close(f)
```

I have written the following code in Java to try to read these data:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class readBinary {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream fileIn = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(argv[0]));
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(argv[1]);
        PrintWriter fileOutWriter = new PrintWriter(fileOut);

        int rows = Integer.parseInt(argv[2]);
        int cols = Integer.parseInt(argv[3]);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                fileOutWriter.print(fileIn.readDouble() + " ");
            }
            fileOutWriter.println();
        }
        fileOutWriter.close();
    }

}
```

In the command line:

```
javac readBinary.java
java readBinary test.txt test_new.txt 3 1
```

The test_new.txt file outputs:

```
4.667261458438315E-62 
1.9035985662475526E185 
4.667261458387024E-62
```

So Java is not picking this up as three doubles correctly.

Thus, I ask, what exactly is the output of writeBin, and how could it be read into Java so that the intended numbers are read in correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java in big-endian by default. Thus please try using `writeBin(..., endian = "big")`

```
f <- file("test.txt", "wb")
writeBin(c(1.2, 2.3, 3.4), f, endian = "big")
close(f)
```